# Debo grabar una expresion PYTHON en un campo copiando el valor de otros campos

Tags: python, string

Tengo 3 campos:

1. Referencia: "name"
2. Numero de factura :"number"
3. nombre clinete: "partner_id"

todos en el objeto: account.invoice

necesito una expresion que haga que en el campo de referencia me aparezca lo siguiente

Referencia: F. Numero de Factura Nombre de Cliente

Muchas Gracias

Soy novato en el asunto.

Comment: Hola @Jose Morales, bienvenido a Stack Overlfow. Para poder dar una respuesta, tu pregunta debe ser clara, incluir lo que has intentado para resolverlo, la salida esperada, el error que recibes. Procura incluir un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Te sugiero revisar el enlace [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ver cómo puedes mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

como dice @Eli, tu pregunta no está formulada todo lo bien que podría estar, aún así, intento darte solución.

Entiendo que este es el objeto:

```
# Entiendo que el diccionario que tienes se parece a este
account={}
account['invoice']={'name':'Juan', 'number': 156, 'partner_id':'156-S'}
print(account) # {'invoice': {'number': 156, 'partner_id': '156-S', 'name': 'Juan'}}
```

Aquí te dejo como sería la linea concreta necesaria para lo que necesitas

```
# dada la información que has puesto, este sería el string que necesitarías obtener del diccionario
'F.{} {}'.format(account['invoice']['number'], account['invoice']['partner_id']) # 'F.156-F.156-F.156-Juan'
```

Y Aquí te dejo el bucle completo utilizando la linea anterior para modificar el objeto

```
# Esta es una función donde te he metido el proceso de cambio de nombre en el objeto que necesitas
def changeName(item):
    print(item)
    item['name']=item['name']='F.{} {}'.format(str(item['number']), item['partner_id'])

# Con este for, puedes obtener el elemento invoice o modificarlo para obtener en loop los elementos que necesites,
# ten en cuenta, que le estoy enviando el primer item del objeto account, por lo que si tu objeto es más complejo, tienes
# que modificar este for para enviar a changeName la información correcta.
 for item in account: 
    # Se envía el elemento del diccionario correspondiente 
     changeName(account[item]) # changeName({'number': 156, 'partner_id': '156-S', 'name': 'Juan'})

# Aquí puedes ver el objeto ya modificado 'in place'
print(account) # {'number': 156, 'partner_id': '156-S', 'name': 'F.156-Juan'}
```

Espero que con esto puedas resolver tu problema, en todo caso, revisa como formular correctamente las preguntas, así te podrán ayudar de forma más concreta.